# How could we identify what component or hook triggered a Suspense boundary?

Tags: reactjs

It feels like this is missing in the Suspense API. But, given a Suspense boundary, how could we identify what triggered its fallback state?

Think:

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}
  <LargeComponentWithMultipleNestedLayers />
</Suspense>
```

In the above example, if we have a large complex component within a Suspense boundary I have no way of knowing what caused its Suspended state. How could we identify this programatically?

Comment: What if you removed the <Suspense> boundary? Just for testing purposes. There may be a stack trace that gives you more info.

Comment: It's not only for debugging purposes, but for metrics too which is why I add "programatically" to the request.